# If not found in first MySQL TABLE, how do I make it do a search in a second TABLE?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working in MySQL/PHP. It's a zip code database. The first table has the zip codes and the average AGI for each zip code. But this is not a complete table of zip codes, because the IRS doesn't include zip code data that has less than 250 tax returns filed. Also, some zip codes are for PO Boxes and there might not be any average AGI data for those zip codes either.

I want to be able to search the first table which has the average AGI by the zip code, and if the zip code is not found there I want it to search the second table, and display a message something this in PHP:

```
echo "The $zipcode was not found." . "<br>";
if (isset($pobox)) {
    echo "Because $zipcode is a PO Box" . "<Br>";
} else {
    echo "It may contain fewer than 250 tax returns filed." . "<br>";
}
```

Here is the query for the MySQL in PHP:

```
$result = mysql_query("
select zip
from zip_codes
where zip=$zipcode;") or exit(mysql_error());
```

The second TABLE, is called zip_code_types which contains if the zip code is for a PO Box, or something else unique about it.

Should this be done by combining the two tables in a single search? Or should two separate queries be done?

How do I check if the first MySQL query doesn't find anything? What is returned and where, is there another function that's needed to check for this? If I'm completely missing how this should be done, please kindly enlighten me. Thanks!

Comment: you could check number of rows returned and proceed further..!

Comment: Do you have some sample data for each table? Is there always a row in `zip_code_types` or is there only a row if the zip code is NOT in `zip_codes`?

Comment: @lc, yes, I have the data for both. There is always a zip code in zip_code_types, but not always a zip code in zip_codes. The zip_codes TABLE has a smaller number of rows because zip code with fewer than 250 tax returns filed are included, nor are most PO Boxes.

Comment: Okay by reading your description I assume one table has zip codes and AGI data and the other has all the zip codes. If that's the case I'd probably join the tables on zip code (assuming they're identical in format) and make sure the join is set up so it returns all the records from the table with all the zip codes in it. Then you can base your if on whether the AGI data exists or not.

Comment: Look at Iwantsimplelife's answer. It will work and it is just a change to the sql query. It is the same as my answer except he adds a good suggestion to use pseudo fields returned from the database to give you an easy way to figure out which table the zip came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use of mysql_ functions is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.**
To answer your question, you could check for number of rows returned by your **SELECT** query and proceed to next query if needed, like:

```
$result = mysql_query("select zip from zip_codes where zip=$zipcode;") or exit(mysql_error());
if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
   //return the result
}
else {
  //your next query here
}
```

Do you mean something like this

Answer (score 1):

If the fact that the data is not in the first table is meaningful then you should do two separate searches. And since you want to present a message it seems it is meaningful. You *could* do it in a single select statement using the 'union' operator, but then you really wouldn't be able to tell when data is coming from one table versus another. You aren't joining anything so outer joins won't help (and they would be ugly and the code to interpret the results would be overly convoluted). No, you are better just doing a couple of searches in my opinion. Someone else may have some other great insight but it isn't that big a deal to search again is it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your query like this

```
$result = mysql_query("select zip from zip_codes where zip='$zipcode'") or exit(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    //query for searching in another table
}
else {
   // your code
}
```

and use `Mysqli` OR `PDO` instead of `Mysql_*`.

Comment: I upgraded 400+ .php files in my portal from Mysql_* old style to PDO style, and it totally makes a difference in security, easiness of reading and robustness. I encourage you to change your old Mysql_* style queries to PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Use a union query but make the queries also return a field containing the source.

Like this.

Select zip, 'zip' as source from zip-codes where zip=$zip
Union
Select zip, 'pobox' as source from poboxs where zip=$zip